# Change primary key from null to not null

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, notnull

I have a field ID that has been set as a primary key and null, I tried to change it to not null with the code below but I got an error saying ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ID failed because one or more objects access this column. how can i change it without dropping the table.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RCHOLE]
ALTER COLUMN ID varchar(18) NOT NULL
```

[image]

Comment: what type of RDBMS you have? The reason I am asking is because I have never heard so far of a DB with a column that is PK and still allows NULLs.

Comment: @EduardUta I'm using SQL Server 2012, and when selecting the design option allow Nulls is ticked.

Comment: therefore RCHOLE.ID is not a PK in your case. A PK is a NOT NULL constraint + UNIQUE constraint. I assume that in your case the column has just a UNIQUE constraint on it (this allows NULLs and it can be used as referenced FK column).

Comment: you are correct @EduardUta but can i change it not to allow nulls

Comment: can you share with us the result of this debug query: SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME='RCHOLE_BLOCK_ID'

Comment: also, please share with us the result of this debug query: select count(*) from dbo.RCHOLE t where t.ID is null

Comment: (General comment): I hope you are aware of the fact that before attempting to create a NOT NULL constraint on a column you have to update all rows that have NULL on that column and set it to non-NULL values (and in your case these should also be unique and uniqueness across all column values should be considered as well).

Comment: @EduardUta I was able to change the ID field to Not Null, by simply  going to Tools from SSMS, Options, Designers, Table and Database Designers and unticked the following option "prevent saving changes that require table re-creation" then I executed the following script. ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RCHOLE]
ALTER COLUMN ID varchar(18) NOT NULL

Answer (score 1):

You Got This Error Because   **RCHOLE_Block_ID** is Dependent On **ID** Column  so You have To Remove Dependency to add NOT Null Constraint.In You Case Error show that  So You have To Remove That Dependency To Apply NOT NULL constraint

Comment: DROP CONSTRAINT RCHOLE_Block_ID;

Answer (score 0):

Potential answer: 
- The RCHOLE.ID column may be a FK in the OtherTable (on OtherTable.RCHOLE_BLOCK_ID). Try to temporary disable that FK, retry adding the not null constraint and then re-add the FK (with check).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the ID field to Not Null, by simply going to Tools from SSMS, Options, Designers, Table and Database Designers and unticked the following option "prevent saving changes that require table re-creation" then I executed the following script.

```js
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RCHOLE] 
ALTER COLUMN ID varchar(18) NOT NULL
```

[image]